# "No such file or directory" error when merging

Tags: windows, youtube-dl

I use `bestvideo+bestaudio`command to download higher than 720p videos from YouTube as audio and video streams are seperated. On my secondary machine I always get `No such file or directory` error after downloading:

```
ERROR: file:video.mp4: No such file or directory
```

This is odd since both of the files exists and are fully functional. By default the program downloads to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` on Windows. I run PowerShell as adminstrator, full command for a video:

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aLjwVVNq4s
```

output:

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aLjwVVNq4s
[youtube] 6aLjwVVNq4s: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 6aLjwVVNq4s: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 6aLjwVVNq4s: Extracting video information
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
[download] Destination: End of the Line [SFM]-6aLjwVVNq4s.f137.mp4
[download] 100% of 133.01MiB in 04:03
[download] Destination: End of the Line [SFM]-6aLjwVVNq4s.f251.webm
[download] 100% of 13.10MiB in 00:19
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "End of the Line [SFM]-6aLjwVVNq4s.mkv"
ERROR: file:End of the Line [SFM]-6aLjwVVNq4s.f137.mp4: No such file or directory
```

youtube-dl `2018.03.26.1` (the latest [version](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/releases) at the time) installed.

Comment: The issue was solved by "invoking" FFmpeg once, by performing a simple file format conversion (I asked this question, I was travelling and didn't have access to my account).

Answer (score 1):

> By default the program downloads to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` on Windows.

As a small niggle, youtuble-dl downloads files to the relative directory it was invoked from.

In the case of an Admin Powershell or cmd prompt, the files are redirected from `C:\Windows\System32` (the default folder for an Admin prompt) to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. This is not typical for non-Admin Powershell or cmd prompts (the folder or redirection).

Regarding your issue, I might try using another path (i.e. use a non-Admin prompt). I encountered no issues with `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` myself but perhaps FFMpeg is choking on it for some reason in your case.

Comment: The issue was solved by "invoking" FFmpeg once, by performing a simple file format conversion (I asked this question, I was travelling and didn't have access to my account).

Comment: Good to hear you got it solved. =)